# How can I read and parse the contents of this text file?

Tags: php

I want read a text file as C++ read it

here is example from the text file

```
(item(name 256) (desc 520)(Index 1)(Image "Wea001") (specialty  (aspeed 700)))
(item   (name 257)  (desc 520)           (Index 2)  (Image "Wea002")(specialty(Attack 16 24)))
```

I want the output like

```
name : 256
Desc : 520
Index : 1
Image : Wea001
Specialty > aspeed : 700
```

---

```
Name : 257
Desc : 520
Index : 2
Image : Wea002
Speciality > Attack : 16 24
```

---

Is that possible?

I tried :

```
preg_match_all('/name\s+(.*?)\)\+\(desc\s+(.*?)\)\+\(Index\s+(.*?)\)/', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
  list (, $name, $desc, $index) = $match;
    echo 'name : '.$name.' <br> Desc : '.$desc.'<br> Index : '.$index.'';
  }
```

But it didn't give me the correct output that I wanted.

Thank you

Comment: Holy cow that is a nasty format. Where is it coming from? Can you change it?

Comment: Lisp attack! So many parenthesis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    $txt = '(item(name 256) (desc 520)(Index 1)(Image "Wea001") (specialty  (aspeed 700))(item   (name 257)  (desc 520)           (Index 2)  (Image "Wea002")(specialty(Attack 16 24)))';

    preg_match_all('/name\s+(?P<name>\w+).*desc\s+(?P<desc>\d+).*Index\s+(?P<index>\d+).*Image\s+(?P<img>.*)\).*specialty\s*\((?P<speciality>.*)\)\)\)/', $txt, $matches);
  foreach($matches['name'] AS $id => $name){
       echo 'name : '.$name.' <br> Desc : '.$matches['desc'][$id].'<br> Index : '.$matches['index'][$id].'<br> speciality : '.$matches['speciality'][$id].'';
}
```

Assuming you have always similar data format