# how to read txt file line by line

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I read and parse the contents of this text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370553/how-can-i-read-and-parse-the-contents-of-this-text-file)

I want read a text file as C++ read it

here is example from the text file

```
(item(name 256) (Index 1)(Image "Wea001")   (specialty  (aspeed 700) (Hit 20)))
(item   (name 257)  (desc 520)           (Index 2)  (Image "Wea002")(specialty(Attack 16 24)))
```

I want the output like

```
name : 256
Index : 1
Image : Wea001
Specialty > aspeed : 700 
Specialty > hit : 20
```

---

```
Name : 257
Desc : 520
Index : 2
Image : Wea002
Speciality > Attack : 16 24
```

---

Is that possible?

Comment: yes it is possible, and the answer could be found with 1 minute of research

Comment: Same question, same poster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370553/how-can-i-read-and-parse-the-contents-of-this-text-file

Comment: You can ask google the [same question](http://www.google.com/#hl=ru&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=how+to+read+text+file+line+by+line+php&oq=how+to+read+text+file+line+by+line+php&gs_l=hp.12..0i8i30.1018.1018.0.3659.1.1.0.0.0.0.192.192.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c.1j2.6uLYxn5TlvI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=1a0c4c47d5b56c7&biw=1175&bih=787) and get a quick answer

Comment: @Dagon that is if you are using only your toes

Comment: "Thank you very much , it working fine" [previous thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370553/how-can-i-read-and-parse-the-contents-of-this-text-file) - so why are you asking again?

Comment: I can tell your a researcher and not someone who wants me to write their code for them

Comment: yes i thanked the person who helped me in the first question, but check the last answer, the code was working fine, but some lines in the text without (desc ) so the code dont read this line

Answer (score 1):

Straight out of php manual:

[fgets()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

> **Example #1 Reading a file line by line**

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

```
<?php
$f = fopen ("fgetstest.php", "r");
$ln= 0;
while ($line= fgets ($f)) {
    ++$ln;
    printf ("%2d: ", $ln);
    if ($line===FALSE) print ("FALSE\n");
    else print ($line);
}
fclose ($f);
```

?>